# Numerically extracting the phase of a sinusoid without constant phase?

Tags: signal-processing

I have experimental data that is proportional to $I(k) = cos(Ak + \phi(k))$, where the phase $\phi(k)$ is not constant for different values of $k$. How would I go about numerically calculating $\phi(k)$? If the phase where constant, a Fourier transform would solve my problem, but I am not sure how this would be done when the signal has a chirp. Would it be possible to fit $\phi(k)$ to coefficients from a Taylor series? Thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure : is $A$ known or not ?

Comment: Not necessarily, though I could modify my experiment to produce data without A. That is to say, if it makes it possible by omission of A, that would be sufficient.